# Enforcing searching before creating

Tags: c#, algorithm, hash

I have a requirement where clients will search for customer data owned by my team and if they don't find, they can create a new customer.

For example, clients can search by organization name in a particular zip code and if they don't find any results, they create a new organization as a customer at that zip code.

We'd like to ensure our clients are strictly doing a "search" before they do a create to avoid duplicates. For this, I was thinking that we hash specific fields of the search request and return that as part of the search response. The client would have to pass this hash value for the create request and we would hash the same fields of the input and compare the hash.

The create happens only if the hashes match.

I'm not sure what this is called and what is the industry standard  for this. Please guide.

Thanks,
Arun

Comment: Why not just perform a search behind the scenes when a 'create' happens and alert the user if what they are creating has already been found? I don't really see a benefit to hashing; even something as small an innocent as a change in case of one letter will miss the duplicate.

Comment: We planned to do that, but that ended up taking more time. Also, as part of microservice architecture, each of these pieces will do specific functionality. I agree with the hashing issue though, but is there any other mechanism around this is what I want to know.

Comment: There really isn't. If you have a handful of fields that determine uniqueness, you need to compare them *somehow*, I just don't see any way around that. Take the time and do it the right way. If you're worried about performance, narrow it down to the most specific subset of fields that need to be unique.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb, just want to be clear on what I mentioned earlier. We tried the 'search before create' from within create and that took more time. Yes there are those specific fields that we have narrowed it down. Uppercase and cleansing special characters before hashing for both methods would be a good start is what I'm thinking. But surprising that I'm the first one having this issue.

Comment: The industry standard is to not force users to search before allowing them to create something, or at least not to try to compare what they searched for with what they're creating. Instead, the standard is to do duplication detection server-side (like how you can't post a question with exactly the same title as another on this site) and/or display existing potential matches during the creation process (like how you see similar questions when posting a question here). If this causes performance issues, you should probably address those issues instead of trying to find another solution.